# Salesforce API call limit

Tags: soap-api, limits

We are getting this error while updating a Custom object we created in Salesforce.

> REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED

We have searched this error and it means we have reached Salesforce daily API limit. We are updating a custom object in Salesforce in batches of 200.

> **Our question is if we want to update 4000 custom object rows at Salesforce by doing it in batches we will be making 20 API calls so
>   how much API count will increase at Salesforce?**

Will it be 20 or 4000 and is there any document we can refer to that how much API call count increase if we do an update at Salesforce.

Answer (score 4):

One API call is one API call, regardless of its size. That means that if you updated 4,000 records with 20 calls, then 20 is how many calls you used. Note that you could have used the Bulk API to update all 4,000 records in about 2 calls instead of 20; that's the purpose of the Bulk API. Keep in mind that all the stuff you might be doing in your org, like using the Developer Console, testing integrations, etc may also be using a lot of API calls. You'll want to run a report on API usage to see which client is the culprit.

Comment: Does API version matters we are using SOAP API version 8 which is very old one?

Comment: @FazeenAhmad No. One API call is one API call, no matter the version or the size of the request.

Comment: Is there any limit of batch in update? like i can not not send more than 20 mb in request or not more than 500 objects.

Comment: @FazeenAhmad Yes, the SOAP limit is 200 records. If you're uploading files, the maximum file size is approximately 39 MB (50 MB of data over the wire). You can read about other __[SOAP API limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apicalls.htm)__, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making 20 API calls they will be counted 20. Every request you are making will be counted as 1. It doesn't matter if you are making these request to update the data or just checking the status.

You can read the KA to get the detail idea.

[How much is the API limit?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003706&type=1)

To understand your current org limit you can refer this document.

[API Request Limits and Allocations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm)

Comment: Does API version matters we are using SOAP API version 8 which is very old one?

Comment: @FazeenAhmad Not really unless you want to use a feature which is not available in this version. Also if Salesforce retire this version as this is very old.

Answer (score 0):

For DE Total number of API calls you can perform in 24-hrs is 15000.
In Single transaction you can perform 100 API calls.

So if you are saying that you are updating 200 records in single API calls, means you are sending data of 200 records in one request body that means you are only making 20 API calls.

But for 24 hours if you are doing it so many times, than only it is possible that you are reaching 15000 call per 24 hours limit.

**Reference :**

[Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm)

[API Request Limits and Allocations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm)

Comment: Does API version matters we are using SOAP API version 8 which is very old one?